# OpenNLP lemmatization example

Tags: nlp, opennlp

Does anyone know where I can find an example of how to use the `SimpleLemmatizer` class in the OpenNLP library, and where I can find a sample english dictionary? It appears to be missing from the documentation.

Comment: `SimpleLemmatizer` has been removed many years ago. Better use `DictionaryLemmatizer` for a dictionary-based approach. See answer by *Collin Bell*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download Dictionary from here - [en-lemmatizer.dict](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-opennlp-auto-tagging/master/src/main/resources/models/en-lemmatizer.dict)

Example :

```
import opennlp.tools.lemmatizer.SimpleLemmatizer;

private static SimpleLemmatizer lemmatizer;

private String lemmatize(String word, String postag) throws IOException {
    if (lemmatizer == null) {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/models/en-lemmatizer.dict");
        lemmatizer = new SimpleLemmatizer(is);
        is.close();
    }
    String lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, postag);
    return lemma;
}
```

Sample code taken from here - [DocumentTaggerService](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-opennlp-auto-tagging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/service/autotagging/DocumentTaggerService.java)

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful!

Comment: Note: This example is outdated, as `SimpleLemmatizer` has been removed many years ago. Therefore, this answer is not up-to-date with modern versions of OpenNLP (>= 2.x).

Answer (score 3):

RAVI did not fully answer the question:

The reason you aren't seeing the SimpleLemmatizer in the autodoc is because it actually doesn't exist.

Use DictionaryLemmatizer instead.

`opennlp.tools.lemmatizer.DictionaryLemmatizer`